# When did the Thirteenth Doctor get her ear pierced?

Tags: doctor-who

Having watched the Season 11 opener [*The Woman Who Fell to Earth*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Woman_Who_Fell_to_Earth), the Thirteenth Doctor doesn't have an ear ring. In the subsequent episode [*The Ghost Monument*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ghost_Monument), we see her running around with an ear ring (I can't tell if it's a clip-on or a piercing).

I didn't see this episode from the very beginning - did she *suddenly* get a pierced ear, or was this also picked up when choosing her new outfit at the end of the first episode?

Comment: Haven't seen the episodes but most likely 2 options. 1) It happened sometime off screen between the episodes likely at the end of episode 1 as you say. 2) She always had pierced ears but only put an earring in it off screen between the episodes.

Comment: Maybe Time Lord ears come out that way.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Toward the end of the first episode of the new season, we see the Doctor travel to a charity shop to buy some clothes. She also seems to have had her ears pierced and her hair and makeup professionally done.

[image]

Noting that the *real* filming location of the shopping sequence is [actually in Cardiff](https://www.walesonline.co.uk/lifestyle/tv/cardiff-charity-shop-doctor-whos-15253259), not Sheffield, that same road contains at least two professional salons that offer nails, hairdressing and ear piercing. The closest is Beauty Nails, Cardiff.

[image]

---

As to the (out-of-universe) meaning of the earrings, this was discussed in an interview with the BBC

> **Q1.** *What's the story behind the ear jewellery?*
>
> **A:** *Jodie and I decided it would be great to have a single earring. I decided it should be bespoke and so needed a jeweller to
> help us design and make it. We met in his workroom and the three of us
> discussed what the earring should represent and we decided it needed
> to start at the top of Jodie’s ear and travel to the ear lobe. The
> story is that the stars are where the Doctor comes from, the chain is
> the journey and the hands of peace represent her love of humans. I
> wanted to make the hands two different colours to represent
> inclusivity so we decided they should be silver and gold. Jodie
> offered to pierce the top of her ear but we didn’t think that would be
> necessary and the jeweller did an amazing job of crafting a piece
> which clips over the top of her ear then the hands go through her
> pierced ear lobe and the chain is attached to the back butterfly. It
> took about 5 weeks from the first conversation to the end result and
> we were thrilled with it.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Ray Holman - Costume Designer Q+A](http://www.bbc.co.uk/blogs/doctorwho/entries/3cfd7b93-2e89-4fec-a7b9-8de903f454f5)</sup></sub>

Comment: Well, this is the first time I've ever seen an answer saying: "the sci-fi character went to this nearby place that isn't shown, but it exists according to Google Maps".

Comment: @Thunderforge - Sometimes it's worth going the extra mile. Or in this case, the extra 134 feet.

Comment: @Thunderforge - there's a number of locations in Cardiff that fill that bill, like that retro diner in Impossible Astronaut

Comment: Hmm, that style of earring looks [oddly familiar](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Bajoran_earring)...

Comment: @Chronocidal - [Indeed](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/File:Rom_wearing_Bajoran_earring.jpg)

Comment: @Chronocidal - I also thought it looked a bit Bajoran, noticing that led me to ask this question.